# How to reduce INDEPENDENT SET to INDEPENDENT SET SIZE?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, reductions

Suppose you are given a polynomial-time algorithm for the following problem related to INDEPENDENT SET:

INDEPENDENT SET VALUE

Input: An undirected graph G.

Output:The size of the largest independent set in G (but not the set itself).

Show how you can use this algorithm to solve the INDEPENDENT SET problem in polynomial time: given a graph G, return an independent set which is as large as possible.

Any help would be really appreciated. I am pretty lost in this question

Comment: Crossposted [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372866/how-to-reduce-independent-set-to-independent-set-size).

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of issues to address, first is what definition of **INDEPENDENT SET** you are using, the "standard" definition is

> **INDEPENDENT SET** (Decision)
> *Input*: A graph $G$ and a number $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
> *Question*: Does $G$ have an independent set of size at least $k$?

This is the decision version of the problem, and it should be pretty obvious how to use **INDEPENDENT SET VALUE** to solve it.

If you however mean the *search* (or *optimization*) version of the problem:

> **INDEPENDENT SET** (Search / almost Optimization)
> *Input*: A graph $G$ and a number $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
> *Output*: An independent set $I\subseteq V$ where $|I| \geq k$.

If we're looking at the optimization version, then we have the optimization criterion "maximise $k$".

In these cases we can still use **INDEPENDENT SET VALUE** to solve the problem in polynomial time. What we want is an algorithm that makes a polynomial number of calls to our **INDEPENDENT SET VALUE** sub-routine, and at each step decides what to do with some element of the graph.

Further hints in spoilers (don't cheat! ;) ):

> Say you have a graph $G$ where the size of the largest independent set is $\alpha(G)$ Consider what happens if you delete a vertex from $G$ to get $G'$, then run the **INDEPENDENT SET VALUE** algorithm on $G'$ - what possible values can you get for $\alpha(G')$, and what does that mean for the vertex you deleted?